# Read xml attribute as object

Tags: c#, xml, .net-core

I have the following simple XML file and I am tying to read the attribute code, using a C# .NET Core Console. I really appetite for any help.

```
<course type="IT" date="19.09.2019">
    <line code="IT001"/>
</course>
```

**UPDATE**
I need the result as an object.

Comment: So have you tried anything yet? I'd strongly recommend using LINQ to XML: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview

Comment: When you say you want it "as an object", what do you mean exactly? A string? (which is an object). Or a class representing the whole XML structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use xml serialization to get a class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Course));
            Course course = (Course)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("course")]
    public class Course
    {
        [XmlAttribute("type")]
        public string _type { get; set; }

        public DateTime _date { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("date")]
        public string date {
            get { return _date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"); }
            set { _date = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "dd.MM.yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); } 
        }


        private string _code { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("line")]
        public Line line
        {
            get { return new Line() { code = _code }; }
            set { _code = value.code; }
        }

    }
    [XmlRoot("line")]
    public class Line
    {
        [XmlAttribute("code")]
        public string code { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to skin this cat.  Here is a solution by making use of XPath

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

xmlDoc.LoadXml("<course type=\"IT\" date=\"19.09.2019\"> <line code=\"IT001\"/></course>");
var attrVal = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/course/line/@code").Value;

Console.WriteLine("Attribute 'code' value is " + attrVal);
```